# Playing subsection of video in android

Tags: android, video, android-videoview

In android I have a 3 min length video. I have three buttons.
On first button click i want the 1st min video play only.
On second button click from 1st min to 2nd min video play only
and on third button click the rest of video.

The order of click can be changed. Is it possible to do it?

I used the below code

```
videoPlayer = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoPlayer);   
    videoPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    videoPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    videoPlayer.setKeepScreenOn(true);    
  //  videoPlayer.setVideoPath(root + "/" + pathToFile);
   // ResourceUtil.setVideo(videoPlayer,"cbse_g08_s01_l01_t01_sc11");
    videoPlayer.setVideoPath(ResourceUtil.getResourceFilePath("cbse_g08_s02_l16_t01_03a",
            MSConstants.RESOURCE_TYPE_VIDEO));


    leftButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             Log.i("arv", "click"+"left"+videoPlayer.getDuration());
            //if(videoPlayer.canSeekBackward()())
                videoPlayer.seekTo(videoPlayer.getDuration());
            videoPlayer.start();
        }
    });

    midButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             Log.i("arv", "click"+"mid"+videoPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
             //if(videoPlayer.canSeekForward())
                 videoPlayer.seekTo(videoPlayer.getDuration()/5);
                videoPlayer.start();
        }
    });

    rightButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             Log.i("arv", "click"+"right");
            //if(videoPlayer.canSeekForward()) 
                videoPlayer.seekTo(videoPlayer.getDuration()/10);
            videoPlayer.start();
        }
    });
```

But it played the video from the given time to end.
Is there any other way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok you just have to create a `Async` class and handle the duration at runtime. Whenever the required duration is achieved the loop is completed and video is pause. Here try this code which has basic functionality of pausing the video as per your need.

```
private class Preview extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {       

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){                  

        //handle any code if u want here
    }


    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //leftButton,rightButton,midButton are booleans you have to make
                    if(leftButton){
                        while(videoPlayer.getCurrentPosition() < videoPlayer.getDuration()/5 )
                          Log.d("!@!@","in loop1");                 
                    }
                    if(midButton){
                        while(videoPlayer.getCurrentPosition() < videoPlayer.getDuration()/10 )
                          Log.d("!@!@","in loop2");                 
                    }
                    if(rightButton){
                        while(videoPlayer.getCurrentPosition() < videoPlayer.getDuration() )
                          Log.d("!@!@","in loop3");                 
                    }

        return null;
    }

    @Override       
    protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
        /**Can pause or stop the videoview/mediaplayer as per your need*/

        videoPlayer.pause();  // <= this is the key ;)
    }       

}
```

After that `execute` async every time on button click.

```
leftButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         Log.i("arv", "click"+"left"+videoPlayer.getDuration());
        //if(videoPlayer.canSeekBackward()())
            videoPlayer.seekTo(videoPlayer.getDuration());
        videoPlayer.start();

        leftButton=true; // <= boolean to be set 
        new Preview().execute(); // <= start Async
    }
});
```

Similarly append in other buttons. Make changes to code as per your needs. Hope it helps. Cheers. :)

Comment: on each play click of buttons...it take some pause (loading time i think) to play it.How i remove this play pause.